# How to remove the first three characters from every row in a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, edit, gsub, subtraction

I have a large data set with a column of text, 20K rows.  Would like to remove the first x number (e.g. 3) of characters at the beginning of each row in that specific column. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Look at `?substr` and also at `?nchar`

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your time and assistance. Very helpful!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with `gsub` function and simple regex. Here is the code:

```
# Fake data frame
df <- data.frame(text_col = c("abcd", "abcde", "abcdef"))
df$text_col <- as.character(df$text_col)

# Replace first 3 chracters with empty string ""
df$text_col <- gsub("^.{0,3}", "", df$text_col)
```

Comment: Great answer and it worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: such a nice great answer. Would you know how to adapt your answer in case we wanted to delete the last three characters instead?

Comment: Use ".{0,3}$" instead of "^.{0,3}".

Answer (score 5):

With the `tidyverse` we can use `str_sub` (and some sample `fruit` text strings) to do this, by directly specifying start and end points:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(some_fruit = fruit)
tbl
#> # A tibble: 80 x 1
#>    some_fruit  
#>    <chr>       
#>  1 apple       
#>  2 apricot     
#>  3 avocado     
#>  4 banana      
#>  5 bell pepper 
#>  6 bilberry    
#>  7 blackberry  
#>  8 blackcurrant
#>  9 blood orange
#> 10 blueberry   
#> # … with 70 more rows
tbl %>%
  mutate(chopped_fruit = str_sub(fruit, 4, -1))
#> # A tibble: 80 x 2
#>    some_fruit   chopped_fruit
#>    <chr>        <chr>        
#>  1 apple        le           
#>  2 apricot      icot         
#>  3 avocado      cado         
#>  4 banana       ana          
#>  5 bell pepper  l pepper     
#>  6 bilberry     berry        
#>  7 blackberry   ckberry      
#>  8 blackcurrant ckcurrant    
#>  9 blood orange od orange    
#> 10 blueberry    eberry       
#> # … with 70 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As usual..so many ways to do things in R!

You can also try `?substring`:

```
lotsofdata <- data.frame(column.1=c("DataPoint1", "DataPoint2", "DataPoint3", "DataPoint4"),
    +                 column2=c("MoreData1","MoreData2","MoreData3", "MoreData4"),
    +                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> head(lotsofdata)
    column.1   column2
1 DataPoint1 MoreData1
2 DataPoint2 MoreData2
3 DataPoint3 MoreData3
4 DataPoint4 MoreData4
```

```
> substring(lotsofdata[,2],4,nchar(lotsofdata[,2]))
[1] "eData1" "eData2" "eData3" "eData4"
```

Or column 1 `[,1]`

```
> substring(lotsofdata[,1],4,nchar(lotsofdata[,1]))
[1] "aPoint1" "aPoint2" "aPoint3" "aPoint4"
```

Then just replace it:

```
x<-substring(lotsofdata[,1],4,nchar(lotsofdata[,1]))

lotsofdata$column.1<-x

> head(lotsofdata)
  column.1   column2
1  aPoint1 MoreData1
2  aPoint2 MoreData2
3  aPoint3 MoreData3
4  aPoint4 MoreData4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.