# R function for removing first 4 characters in a column?

Tags: r, function, substring, substr

I have a data frame (Data) and I have created a new column with the first four characters of each vector in a column (Details) using substr.

Here is the code:

```
Data$Years = substr(Data$Details, 1, 5)
```

How would I use `substr` (or another function) to remove the same first four characters from the original (Details) column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the first three characters from every row in a column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836518/how-to-remove-the-first-three-characters-from-every-row-in-a-column-in-r)

Answer (score 4):

We can specify the `first` (in `substring`) or `start` in `substr` as the 5th character and `last` (not needed in `substring` as it is by default `last = 1000000L`) or `stop` in `substr` as the last character (`nchar`)

```
substring(Data$Details, 5)
```

Or with `substr`

```
substr(Data$Details, 5, nchar(Data$Details))
```

---

Or using a regex to match any character (`.` - repeated 4 times) from the start (`^`) of the string and replace with blank (`""`)

```
sub("^....", "", Data$Details)
```